# select next/closest div under td tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide `div` with class question when `$row[12]` have some values

```
 <td class="status">
     <div class="recstatus">$row[12]</div>
     <div class="question">

     //something

     </div>

    </td>
```

Here goes JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.statusselect').each(function () {
       // someting like this it's not working
       var status = $(this).next('.recstatus');
    if ( status.text() == '1' || status.text() == '2' ||  status.text() == '3' ||  status.text() == '4' ) {
       //something like this but it's not working too
       $(this).next('.question').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

I want to use this next/closest div because this form is in cycle

Comment: where is your `.statusselect` ?

Comment: perhaps you wanted to use `$('.recstatus').next('.question')` instead of `$(this).next('.question')`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are selecting the elements with class of `status` and not `statusselect`, `.recstatus` are descendant elements, you should either use `.find()` or `.children()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
    $('.status').filter(function() { 
        var t = $(this).find('.recstatus').text();
        return $.inArray(t, arr) > -1;  
    }).find('.question').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   solved i take $('.recstatus').each not $('td').each 

 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.recstatus').each(function () {
         if ( $(this).text() == '1' || $(this).text() == '2' ||  $(this).text() == '3' ||  $(this).text() == '4' ) {
           $(this).next(".question").hide();
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for finding the closest for example:

```
$('td.status').closest('div')
```

Then, use this to get the next closest:

```
$('td.status').closest('div').next('div')
```

Refer to this: http://api.jquery.com/closest/